# Let $(A_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of events. Prove that $\mathbb{P}(A_{n})$ converges to $0$ when $n\to\infty$ iff $1_{A_n}\to 0$ in probability.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(A_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of events. Prove that $\mathbb{P}(A_{n})$ converges to $0$ when $n\to\infty$ iff $1_{A_{n}}\to 0$ in probability. Here $1_{A_{n}}$ is the indicator function.

This is what I have tried.

Let us start with the definition of convergence in probability:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega : |1_{A_{n}}(\omega) - 0(\omega)| \geq \varepsilon\}) = 0
\end{align*}
for every possible value of $\varepsilon > 0$. In particular, if we choose $\varepsilon = 1/2$, we conclude the desired claim:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega : |1_{A_{n}}(\omega) - 0(\omega)| \geq 1/2\}) & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega : 1_{A_{n}}(\omega) \geq 1/2\}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_{n}) = 0 
\end{align*}

I am concerned about the reverse direction $(\Rightarrow)$. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

Your work also helps prove the reverse direction.

Suppose $P(A_n) \to 0$.

If $\epsilon \le 1$, then you've already shown $P(|1_{A_n} - 0| \ge \epsilon) = P(A_n)$, which converges to zero by the assumption.

If $\epsilon > 1$, then $P(|1_{A_n} - 0| \ge \epsilon) = 0$ already.